# Does anyone still use MINIX?

Tags: minix

I was just curious if anyone still use MINIX and for what purposes.

I found [this article](http://www.freesoftwaremagazine.com/articles/minix) but it doesn't go in detail about who uses it and for what.

Thanks

Comment: If you're looking for the MINIX community, [start here](http://www.minix3.org/community/index.html).

Comment: not necessarily, just curious whether there is any application outside the academia.  but thanks

Comment: Ask Tanenbaum , he may be...........

Comment: MINIX is very widely deployed if you consider that it is used in the Intel Management Engine on every modern Intel CPU. Just this week, this has surfaced in the spotlight as a possible local security vulnerability on any Intel computer.  See this article https://www.networkworld.com/article/3236064/servers/minix-the-most-popular-os-in-the-world-thanks-to-intel.html and also for an interesting historical bit from 1992, the Tanenbaum/Torvalds debate https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tanenbaum%E2%80%93Torvalds_debate

Answer (score 1):

We (a northern UK University) are considering it as part of teaching Operating Systems to students.